# Angular7 - Problem in refreshing a seekbar (input range) using a function

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm writing a music player using angular7, and this is the html code of my component:

```xml
<div class="track-controller">
  <small>{{musicPlayerService.getCurrentTime()}}</small>
    <div class="progress-wrap">
      <input type="range" class="progress" [value]="musicPlayerService.getProgress()" min="0" max="100" step="1"
                  #duration (input)="musicPlayerService.setProgress(toNumber(duration.value)) ">
      <div class="progress-foreground" [style.width.%] ="musicPlayerService.getProgress()"></div>
      </div>
  <small>{{musicPlayerService.getTrackDuration()}}</small>
</div>
```

As you can see I call 4 functions from my music player service, but in particular these 2 functions should be called continuously to update my seekbar:

`getCurrentTime():` this is used to get the track current time in seconds

`getProgress():` this is used to get the current track %, to update the seekbar

The problem is that as far a I can see, these 2 functions are called only once (when my musicPlayerService start playing the track), and even more strange: everytime I click randomly on the page with my mouse or I move the mouse pointer on a link.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make getter/setter for `currentTime` and `progress`.

```
get currentTime() {
    return this._currentTime;
}

get progress() {
    return this._progress;
}

set currentTime(val) {
    this._currentTime = val
}

set progress() {
    this.progress = val
}
```

When you start your player, say in `ngOnInit()`, keep updating these variables in a `timer()`

```
<div class="track-controller">
  <small>{{currentTime}}</small>
    <div class="progress-wrap">
      <input type="range" class="progress" [value]="currentTime" min="0" max="100" step="1"
                  #duration (input)="musicPlayerService.setProgress(toNumber(duration.value)) ">
      <div class="progress-foreground" [style.width.%] ="progress"></div>
      </div>
  <small>{{musicPlayerService.getTrackDuration()}}</small>
</div>
```

Say:

```
timerSub: Subscription;
yourUpdateDuration = 1000;
ngOnInit() {
    this.timerSub = timer(0, yourUpdateDuration).subscribe(() => {
        this.currentTime = this.musicPlayerService.getCurrentTime();
        this.progress = this.musicPlayerService.getProgress();
    });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.timerSub) {
        this.timerSub.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Comment: So using a timer is really the only solution? :/

Comment: @LucaD'Amico Somewhere some task has got to happen so that angular will get to know that it has to perform change detection. Maybe a timer in the service itself, once the timer will run, angular will check the bindings in the view. You said your `getCurrentTime()` and `getProgress()` were getting called randomly when you were clicking over the screen. This happens because angular does change detection on browser events like "input", "button click", etc.

Comment: Okay I was hoping to avoid using a timer, but well, if that's the only solution... I'm going to try to implement it, and I'll let you know (I'll accept your answer then). Thanks.